# Does having an afro hairstyle have an advantage in doing headers?

Tags: football

Would the hair have a cushion effect that makes them have more grip and control of the ball in the air?

Comment: Having played football as a defender with both short and long hair at various times, when a header is mistimed and you strike it with the top of your head, having long hair actually does make it hurt less. However, the ball should not be headed that high and is normally struck with the forehead, so the hair has little difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, the last thing you want when heading the ball is more cushioning as that equals less power - as a defensive header, you want it going as far downfield as possible, and as an attacking header you again want it going as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2):

In a perfect header, the ball is played to the forhead. As far as I know, there is no player with an afro on his forhead (or hair at least). Most players, with long hair, use auxiliaries, such as hair bands, so that the vision is not impaired by the face falling hair.